# Multiplication of a power series and a finite-order polynomial

Tags: summation, power-series, convolution, formal-power-series

I am trying to find a general expression for the coefficients of the power series that results from the multiplication of a polynomial and a power series. I have looked at this post [Convolution and multiplication of polynomials is the same?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937630/convolution-and-multiplication-of-polynomials-is-the-same?answertab=createdasc#tab-top) which deals with multiplication of two finite-order polynomials, but this doesn't work for the case I have described, and I can't see how to adapt it.

In short, I have:

\begin{equation}
f\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \theta_i x^i \quad \mbox{and} \quad g\left(x\right)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_jx^j \quad \mbox{so} \quad f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_j\theta_i x^j x^i 
\end{equation}

so polynomial $f$ is of order $n-1$ and $g$ is of infinite order. However, I need this to have a single power of $x$ and can't see how to simplify this - any help gratefully received!

Comment: A comment: by definition, a polynomial is of finite order. Otherwise, it is called a [Formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). Referenced Wikipedia article covers the multiplication of formal power series. Therefore, I suggest closing the question as what you ask for is a multiplication of power series.

Comment: Thanks - I will edit to make that clearer!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even after the OP's edit, I agree with @mathcounterexamples.net 's first comment.

Comment: The referenced page does not consider multiplication of a formal power series by a polynomial though - it only covers multiplication of two formal power series - my question is different and not covered by the example.

Comment: @hydrologist A polynomial is just a formal power series having a finite number of non-vanishing coefficients.

Comment: Do you mean as described here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888431/product-between-an-infinite-and-a-finite-power-series?

Comment: @Somos - yes, thank you!